# Filtering building types in the Google Places API

Tags: android, google-places-api

for an android application I am developing I want to find nearby pubs of the current location. The first thing that came in my mind to use was google places using the google places api.

So after looking up the docoumentation I made a simple test suite to get the result from the api all working fine using my API key etc... Then I tried filtering it so it would only show pubs/nightclubs. After looking up the list of supported types (http://code.google.com/intl/nl-NL/apis/maps/documentation/places/supported_types.html) I decided that 'bar', 'cafe' and 'night_club' are types which would match a pub. 
But after applying that filter it only found like 1 out of 50 pubs in the range I provided. So I tried looking closer by getting all the places in a 50m radius from a point where I know alot of pubs are. There I noticed most pubs just have the type 'establishment' however the google places app that comes with google maps does find the pubs just fine if I select pubs in the menu.
Is there anyone that has a suggestion what to use to just find pubs as those types filter don't seem to work. Or did i miss something?

Comment: Hiii I am working on the same kind of application,I am getting ZERO_RESULTS as a response from the server.Can u plz share some sample code for doing this.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Google API's documentation, in contradiction to `Y.A.P.'s statement` explains the pipe symbol to act as an `OR` and not as an `AND`:

`types (optional)` — Restricts the results to Places matching at least one of the specified types. Types should be separated with a pipe symbol (`type1|type2|etc`).

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/#PlaceSearchRequests

Answer (score 0):

This will be a late one ;) but: pub|food will find places of type pub AND food. Only places with those two types will appear in response. If you would like get pubs and food make it two query for each other.

Answer (score 0):

All businesses are categorized under the type `establishment` until Google has enough metadata about a place to categorize it under more specific place types like `bar`, `cafe` and `night_club`.

A work around that may find more results is to use the `keyword` parameter in your request with something like 'bar' as the value.

As per the documentation: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/

- The `keyword` parameter is matched against all available fields, including but not limited to name, type, and address, as well as customer reviews and other third-party content.